# How to replace the nth occurrence of a sttring in a file using sed

Tags: sed

Is there any way to replace the nth occurrence of a string in a file using sed?

How can i change it so that it replaces the nth occurrence?

My file contents the following lines:

```
first line 
second line 
third line
 jack
fifth line 
jack
 seventh line
```

consider a variable `var = jill`.

I want to replace the 2nd occurrence of jack with value of variable `$var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/jack/'"$var"'/2' file
```

This slurps the file into memory and then substitutes the second occurence of `jack` for `$var`.

EDIT:

1. `:a` is a place holder for a `b` command, it tell sed to break/jump to position i.e `ba` jump to `:a`.
2. `$!` is an address. `$` means end of file and `!` means not. Put together this means any address which is not-the-end-of-file.
3. `{...}` groups the commands between the braces.
4. `N` appends a newline and then the next line to the pattern space except when there are no more lines when it passes sed to just passed the last command (if the `-n` is not set it will print what ever is in the pattern space, if `-n` is set it will just end processing).
5. `s/jack/'$var"'/2` this is a sed substitution command and replaces the second occurrence of `jack` by the contents of `$var`. N.B. the `'...'` which effectively breaks out sed commands into the underlying shell and  then back again allowing the shell variable to be interpolated.

In summary the whole file is slurped into memory and the second occurrence of `jack` is replaced by the contents of `$var`.

In most cases this could by replaced by:

```
sed -z 's/jack/'"$var"'/2' file
```

Comment: can you explain me what this thing is doing :a;$!{N;ba};

Comment: @subhashnerella without knowing what $var holds I can only guess that all slashes need to escaped by prepending a backslash. In your comment `</Attribute>` is not. If slashes are prevelant in the pattern and replacement it would be best to use an alternative delimiter e.g. `#`

Comment: @subhashnerella `:a;$!{N;ba};` reads the complete file into the pattern space.

Comment: as you good know, you should give an explanation of your solution completely, not in comment and short.

Comment: @HosseinVatani see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version if you like to use `awk`

```
awk -v c="$var" '/jack/ && ++a==2 {sub(/jack/,c)}1' file
first line
second line
third line
 jack
fifth line
jill
 seventh line
```

Comment: how would the command if i want to insert jill taken from variable in the second occurence of jack so that it would appear like jajillck?

Comment: @subhashnerella This will divided input in two and add a string inn between: `echo "jack" | awk '{s=length($1)/2;print substr($1,0,s)"jill"substr($1,s+1)}'`

Comment: Be wary if you want to `sub()` a specific field, i.e. `sub(/jack/,c,$1)`. This will trim original spaces in the output.