# How to remove the nth occurrence of a substring from each line on four 100GB files

Tags: node.js, csv, text, sed

I have 4 100GB csv files where two fields need to be concatenated. Luckily the two fields are next to each other.

My thought is to remove the 41st occurence of `","` from each line and then my two fields will be properly united and ready to be uploaded to an analytical tool that I use.

The development machine is a Windows 10 machine with 4 x 3.6GHz and 64G RAM and I push the file to a server on Centos 7 system with 40 x 2.4GHz and 512G RAM. I have sudo access on the server and I can technically change the file there if someone has a solution that is dependent on Linux tools. The idea is to accomplish the task in the fastest/easiest way possible. I have to repeat this task monthly and would be ecstatic to automate it.

My original way of accomplishing this was to load the csv to MySQL, concat the fields and remove the old fields. Export the table as a csv again and push to the server. This takes two days and is laborious.

Right now I'm torn between learning to use **sed** or using a something I'm more familiar with like node.js to stream the files line by line into a new file and then push those to the server.

If you recommend using sed, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753136/how-to-replace-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-sttring-in-a-file-using-sed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817798/how-to-replace-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string-using-sed) but don't know how to remove the nth occurrence ***from each line***.

**Edit:** Cyrus asked for a sample input/output.
Input file formatted thusly:

```
"field1","field2",".........","field41","field42","......
```

Output file formatted like so:

```
"field1","field2",".........","field41field42","......
```

Comment: does your csv also has `,` in between double quotes ?

Comment: The "from each line" part is basically the whole idea of sed and similar tools, all commands are applied to each line of input.

Comment: How familiar are you with regular expressions?  There are some *nix command-line utilities that do that with regular expressions.  (sed might even be one of them)

Comment: If I understand you question, there is no occurrence of `","` except to delimit fields. We can safely assume that the 41st occurrence of  `","` is exactly between the two fields.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I'm tired of people coming along and marking questions an answers down when they don't have anything constructive to say.

Comment: With these huge files, one concern would be disk space as most of the text processing tools will create a temporary file to write the changes. I found this very nice writeup: http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove 41st occurrence of `,` then you can try :

```
sed -i 's/","//41' file
```

Comment: Would this work? `sed -i 's/\"\,\"//41' file.csv` Does sed create the new file? The double quotes are necessary to include because they enclose the two strings that have to be joined.

Comment: No space necessary, but the double quotes are.

Comment: Can you  paste your input line here ?

Comment: @AuntJamaima: `sed -i` wont create the new file and will do required changes in the file itself.

Comment: Can you verify the necessary syntax to remove the double quotes with the comma?

Comment: This should work: `sed 's/","//41' file.csv > new.csv`

Comment: @AuntJamaima: This should work but depends if you need results in new file or in same one. If required in same file then use `sed -i`. Also are you sure that it'll be the `41st` occurrence ?

Comment: The only reason to want a new file is so if I mess up I don't have to copy the huge file over again if I mess up.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you batMan and Cyrus. It worked great. It's easily faster than any alternative I had heard of before today.

Comment: To be clear, `sed -i` DOES create a new file but then it copies it back into the original so you will have 2 massive files while sed is running if that's why you're asking about that.

Comment: Just be aware that will fail if a field contains escaped quotes around a comma (as can be produced by Excel and conforms to the RFC), e.g. a field like `"fieldNpart1"",""fieldNpart2"`. It's unlikely to occur of course but since your files are huge and we don't know what's generating them - never say never...